# How do I move a site from one url to another?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have an ASP.NET web application hosted on DiscountASP.NET with its domain name registered on GoDaddy.  This site is working perfectly and runs great, but I hate the domain name.

So now, I decide to purchase a domain name I like better.  How do I set it up so that this domain name runs the same web app as my original application, but using the new domain name instead of the old one (i.e. I don't want to redirect to the old url, I want everything to work under the new url)?

Answer (score 6):

This should be quite simple.  Go to the host/registrar of your new domain and point it to the same ip addresses that the godaddy url points to.

You can have the old url and new url coexist.  The DNS servers just map to the the physical IP your app is hosted on.

If you've been naughty and use absolute urls/directories in your app, you will have to rewrite some code.  All the while reciting the mantra... that's why I should have used relative references...

Answer (score 2):

Either move the application files over and create a redirect from the old URL to the new, or set up a rewrite under the new URL to transparently pass requests to the existing one.